# Is it possible to secure only one spring boot rest endpoint via MTLS

Tags: spring-boot, api, x509certificate, mtls

Is it possible to secure only one spring boot rest endpoint via x509Certificate? (MTLS)

Comment: I suggest you to go through how ssl with Spring Boot microservices combination works [reference] (https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security)

Comment: Did you find a solution for your question?